# Open .doc file directly from sharepoint

Tags: vb.net, sharepoint-2010, ms-word

i want to open .doc file from sharepoint library for editing in C#

my code is

```
Dim process As Process = New Process()
process.Start("https://somename.sharepoint.com/sites/C1/DocLib/mydoc.doc")
```

it is opening but i unable to save the document after editing.

How to save the document.

Comment: Looks like it is `vb.net` syntax but..

Comment: you should be able to check-out documents if you use the SharePoint APIs, see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms454425.aspx

Comment: Thanks @Davide i did what you suggested, but still the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

what you can do is use the office interop for word to open the file, do the editing then save it locally. afterwards, use the **Copy** web service of sharepoint to overwrite the file in the document library.

links:

[Copy method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/copy%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

[Word Interop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.documentclass.save%28v=office.11%29.aspx)

let me know if you need other references.